# Multi threading processing

Tags: multithreading, semaphore

I have a matrix of a big size say 20000*20000 and this matrix keeps on changing every iteration. The matrix is being produced in Fortran, and Fortran calls a C++ function that processes the matrix into block diagonal form. I would like to have the c++ function creates two threads (using C++11) where each will handle 10000 * 10000. I can easily break the matrix into two parts since it's a special matrix. The matrix elements keeps on changing every iterations and if I create and join (kill) the two threads every iteration the over head becomes way expensive and the point of using multi-threading approach is lost. I decided to do the iterations inside the threads; however, I am not sure if I can keep the threads waiting for the updated matrix in order to solve in the next interation (we need to go back to Fortran to calculate the new matrix through).

The point I am stuck at is the following:
When I create the two threads from the function in c++, that function will return to Fortran and the function instance is destroyed (right?). What happen to the two threads that are currently waiting for the new matrix ?

Comment: What is "the function instance" exactly?

Comment: Let's assume the function that is being called from Fortran is called "calculate_parallel", this function returns void. This function creates the two threads and returns before joining them. This is what I meant by function instance, which is basically the time between the function call and the function return.

Comment: Then you can just make the two threads static.